# Send HTML with local links and receive at gmail account

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, gmail

I need to create HTML links and email them to other users with gmail account. This HTML contains links to local files (it's for internal use and all users has access to local files)

I send:

```
<a href="smb://server/folder/file.jpg">Mac OSX</a>
<a href="file:////server/folder/file.jpg">Windows</a>
<a href="file://///server/folder/file.jpg">Windows test</a>
```

But gmail doesn't show links, only text and I can't click and go to the file.

What I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail is filtering out those links because they suspect they are malicious in nature. typically hyperlinks in emails point to websites, not to local network files. As a result, they look suspicious and are removed.